# Files created through Cygwin (calling a shell script) don't have correct Windows permissions

Tags: windows, bash, cygwin

I am currently running Cygwin on a target Windows Server 2003 machine to fire off a shell script that, among other things, creates a bunch of files on disc. However after the files are created I no longer have permissions to manipulate them through Windows.

When the files are created the owner is getting set to 'SYSTEM' and the permissions for `Administrators/Creator Group/Creator Owner/system` are set to only 'special permissions' and nothing else. 
The permissions for Everyone and Users have Read & Execute, List folder contents and Read.

My problem is that I cannot delete/modify the files now through Windows. I would prefer to have something built into my scripts (either the shell script or something to call in Cygwin) that would allow Administrators full control on the folder and all contents.

My current workaround has been to either do file modifications through Cygwin but this is not preferable. I have also used `setfacl -r -m default:other:rwx` to add write permissions for the 'Users' group but it doesn't appear to have a recursive option and still doesn't give 'full control'

Is there a better way to use `setfacl`? Can I call the shell script using different/elevated permissions?

Results of `getfacl` on a newly created directory:

```
$ getfacl Directory/
# file: Directory/
# owner: SYSTEM
# group: root
user::rwx
group::r-x
group:Users:rwx
mask:rwx
other:r-x
default:user::rwx
default:group::r-x
default:group:Users:rwx
default:mask:rwx
default:other:r-x
```

Comment: `find /cygdrive/c/Users -exec setfacl -r -m default:other:rwx {} \;` to emulate a 'recursive' mode to `setfacl`

Comment: I'd love an explanation as to how to just use the standard permissions that would have been used if the file were created outside of Cygwin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try setting `umask`:

```
umask u=rwx,g=rwx,o=rwx
```

That should give user, group, and other read/write/execute on any newly created dirs.

If you only want the modified `umask` permanently, you can add it to your `.bash_profile`

---

**Edit** - *Added example of mkdir before/after umask.*

Here's the output of `getfacl` on a directory created before I set `umask`:

```
[/cygdrive/c/Documents and Settings/NOYB/Desktop]
==> getfacl test_wo_umask/
# file: test_wo_umask/
# owner: NOYB
# group: Domain Users
user::rwx
group::r-x
group:root:rwx
group:SYSTEM:rwx
mask:rwx
other:r-x
default:user::rwx
default:user:NOYB:rwx
default:group::r-x
default:group:root:rwx
default:group:SYSTEM:rwx
default:mask:rwx
default:other:r-x
```

Here's the output of `getfacl` on a directory created after I set `umask`:

```
[/cygdrive/c/Documents and Settings/NOYB/Desktop]
==> getfacl test_w_umask/
# file: test_w_umask/
# owner: NOYB
# group: Domain Users
user::rwx
group::rwx
group:root:rwx
group:SYSTEM:rwx
mask:rwx
other:rwx
default:user::rwx
default:user:NOYB:rwx
default:group::rwx
default:group:root:rwx
default:group:SYSTEM:rwx
default:mask:rwx
default:other:rwx
```

Comment: Worked great! fyi - I was using a combination of cp and mkrdir statements to create the final structure. After setting umask before calling my script it gave full control to Administrators as well as System which is enough for my purposes.